# OpenCV: imwrite is not working when trying to save patches

Tags: opencv

I am using the library patchify to create patches of shape (224,224,3) of an image (test.jpg) of shape (3136,4032,3), and then unpatchify to put them back together. To create the patches I use:

```
img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
patches_img = patchify(img, (224,224,3), step=224)
```

After creating the patches, I want to save each patch in a chosen directory, using cv2.imwrite:

```
for i in range(patches_img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(patches_img.shape[1]):
        single_patch_img = patches_img[i,j,:,:]
        if not cv2.imwrite('patches/images/' + 'image_' + str(img) + '_'+ str(i)+str(j)+'.jpg', single_patch_img):
            raise Exception("Could not write the image")
```

I've written raise exception cause when cv2.imwrite fails, it fails silently.
So when I run the cv2.imwrite, Exception occurs. It's probably something related to the way I am going through each patch, but I am having a hard time finding the problem.

Any suggestion would be very welcome, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could identify two issues:

- Replace `single_patch_img = patches_img[i,j,:,:]` with:

  ```
   single_patch_img = patches_img[i, j, 0, :, :, :]
  ```
- Replace `cv2.imwrite('patches/images/' + 'image_' + str(img) + '_'+ str(i)+str(j)+'.jpg', single_patch_img)`

  ```
   cv2.imwrite('patches/images/' + 'image_' + '_'+ str(i)+str(j)+'.jpg', single_patch_img)
  ```

---

The shape of `patches_img` is `(14, 18, 1, 224, 224, 3)`, and the expected shape of the patch image is `(224, 224, 3)`.
The conclusion is that the relevant patch indices are the last three: `patches_img[i, j, 0, :, :, :]`.

---

In the command `cv2.imwrite('patches/images/' + 'image_' + str(img) + '_'+ str(i)+str(j)+'.jpg', single_patch_img)`
you are using: `str(img)`

`str(img)` converts the NumPy array `img` to string.
The result is something like `'[[[103 119 142]\n  [103 119 142]\n  [103 119 142]\n  ...\n  [ 12  26  44]\n  [ 12  26  45]\n` ...

This is not a legal file name.
You may remove the `str(img)` part or replace it with a valid string.

---

Corrected code sample:

```python
import cv2
from patchify import patchify

img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
patches_img = patchify(img, (224,224,3), step=224)

for i in range(patches_img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(patches_img.shape[1]):
        single_patch_img = patches_img[i, j, 0, :, :, :]
        # if not cv2.imwrite('patches/images/' + 'image_' + '_'+ str(i)+str(j)+'.jpg', single_patch_img):
        if not cv2.imwrite('patches/images/' + 'image_' + '_'+ str(i).zfill(2) + '_' + str(j).zfill(2) + '.jpg', single_patch_img):
            raise Exception("Could not write the image")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation, it completely solved the issue.

Comment: Hey @Rotem , do you think you can help me with another question I have just posted, related to the code in this question? Thank you in advance!